3D plotting of parametric curved surface
Imagine I want the 3D plot of a solid object that has height $H$ and a circular base of radius $R$. The radius of the horizontal cross-section of the object at height $z$ above the base reduces with $z$ ($0 \leq z \leq H$) according to the formula $R_z = R e^{-z/H}$. Additionally, the cross-section is a sector of the circle: the full circle ($2\pi$ radians) at the base but reducing linearly with height to $\pi$ radians at height $z = H$. The figure shows the horizontal cross-section of the object at the base, at the mid-height, and at the top. The following is a cross-sectional scheme of what I mean, at three heights:

I tried to plot it by parametrizing the radius and angle, which gives me a good approximation, for $R=1$ and $H=2$,
R = 1;
H = 2; 
radius[z_] := R  Exp[-z/H]
theta[z_] := 2  Pi - (Pi  z)/H
x[r_, t_, z_] := r  Cos[t]
y[r_, t_, z_] := r  Sin[t]
zCoord[z_] := z
sideFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[radius[z], t, z], y[radius[z], t, z], 
    zCoord[z]}, {z, 0, H}, {t, 0, theta[z]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Blue], Mesh -> None];
bottomFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[radius[0], t, 0], y[radius[0], t, 0], 0}, {t, 0,
     theta[0]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Blue], 
   Mesh -> None];
topFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[radius[H], t, H], y[radius[H], t, H], H}, {t, 0,
     theta[H]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Blue], 
   Mesh -> None];
topLine = 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, 
    Line[{{x[radius[H], 0, H], y[radius[H], 0, H], 
       H}, {x[radius[H], theta[H], H], y[radius[H], theta[H], H], 
       H}}]}];

Show[sideFilled, bottomFilled, topFilled, topLine, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Boxed -> True]


However, I cannot seem to fill the three surfaces: both bases and the side curved surface around the "cone". Any idea how to include these?

Updated
We construct the level sets.
R = 1;
H = 2;
radius[z_] := R Exp[-z/H];
theta[z_] := 2 Pi - (Pi z)/H;
ptss = Table[
   Join[{{0, 0, z}}, 
    Table[{radius[z]*Cos[θ], radius[z]*Sin[θ], 
      z}, {θ, Subdivide[0, theta[z], 201]}]], {z, 
    Subdivide[0.001, H, 401]}];
Graphics3D[Line[ptss[[1 ;; -1 ;; 10]]], Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.5, -2, 1.5}]



And buid the solid by thread the level sets and seal the bottom and top.

{m, n, p} = Dimensions[ptss];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Catenate[
   ptss], {Table[
    Polygon[{{#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]}, {#1[[2]], #1[[1]], #2[[
          2]]}}] & @@@ 
     Thread@{Partition[Range[1, n] + j*n, 2, 1, 1], 
       Partition[Range[1, n] + (j + 1)*n, 2, 1, 1]}, {j, 0, m - 2}], 
   Polygon[Range[1, n] + (m - 1)*n], Polygon[Range[1, n]]}]



2.24709

Edit
To get a smooth filling,we seperately draw the pieces of boundary surfaces.
Clear["Global`*"];
R = 1;
H = 2;
radius[z_] := R   Exp[-z/H];
theta[z_] := 2   Pi - (Pi   z)/H;
sideFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}, {z, 0, 
    H}, {t, 0, theta[z]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Blue], 
   Mesh -> None];
bottomFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{1 - s, 
      s} . {{0, 0, z}, {radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}} /. 
    z -> 0, {t, 0, theta[z] /. z -> 0}, {s, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None];
topFilled = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{1 - s, 
      s} . {{0, 0, z}, {radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}} /. 
    z -> H, {t, 0, theta[z] /. z -> H}, {s, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
Filled1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{1 - s, 
      s} . {{0, 0, z}, {radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}} /. 
    t -> theta[z], {z, 0, H}, {s, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Filled2 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{1 - s, 
      s} . {{0, 0, z}, {radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}} /. 
    t -> 0, {z, 0, H}, {s, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None];
Show[sideFilled, topFilled, bottomFilled, Filled1, Filled2, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]



If we set MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{H/ 2}}, PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 2, MeshStyle -> Tube[.02], we can see that when z=H/2, the section is a 3/4 Disk.


Original

Not so smoothing.

Clear["Global`*"];
R = 1;
H = 2;
radius[z_] := R   Exp[-z/H];
theta[z_] := 2   Pi - (Pi   z)/H;
reg = ParametricRegion[{1 - s, 
    s} . {{0, 0, z}, {radius[z]*Cos[t], radius[z]*Sin[t], z}}, {{z, 0,
     H}, {t, 0, theta[z]}, {s, 0, 1}}];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .01]



This is great! Just a minor question. Would it be possible to include the possibility of having a full rotation by $z=H$. Theoretically, I would do theta[z_] := 2Pi - 2(Pi z)/H;, but I get an endpoint issue. To see what I mean, try theta[z_] := 2Pi - 1.999 (Pi z)/H;

@samwolfe Do you mean Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{radius[z], z}, {z, 0, H}],   RevolutionPlot3D[{r, 0}, {r, 0, radius[0]}, {θ, 0, 2 π},    Mesh -> None],   RevolutionPlot3D[{r, H}, {r, 0, radius[H]}, {θ, 0, 2 π},    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Cyan], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] ?

No, I mean allowing the circle to vanish with height. Try replacing my second version of theta in your code and you will see what I mean. Basically making the angle from $0$ to $2\pi$.

The circle would not vanish until $\theta \to \infty$ or $ z \to  \infty$

H = 2; R = 1; thmax = Pi; r[t_] = R Exp[-t/Pi]; z[t_] = t H/Pi;
shell = ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th + v], r[th] Sin[th + v], 
    z[th]}, {th, 0, thmax}, {v, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
filament = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th], r[th] Sin[th], z[th]}, {th, 0, 
    thmax}, PlotLabel -> Space_ Curve_on _CCS _SOLID, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
Show[{filament, shell}, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> ConstCompressiveStressSOLID]

Not too different. Since
$$ \frac{dz}{d\theta}= \frac{z}{\theta}=\frac{H}{\pi}$$
(for initial condition at base) and $z$ linearity we can also parameterize with
$$r(\theta)= R e^{-z/H} ~= R e^{-\theta/\pi}$$
for a half of the shell. The portions of planes $\theta=0, z=0$ can be included.

As to the query by @sam wolfe for full rotation $2\pi$ of same height $H=2$, set $ H=R=1, \text{thmax} =2 \pi $ to get a more twisted shell:

